# using name column in belongsToMany relation instead of id

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two Models one is Offer (for offers table) and other is Brand (for brands table). There is a "many to many" relationship between these models.

I have a table offer_brands that maps the relation between these two tables. In this table, I have offer_id column that links this table to offers table and brand column that links this table to the brands table **usind brand_name column in brands table.**

In Brand Model I want a relation that return all the offers.

I know I can do it like

```
public function offers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Offer::class, 'offer_brands', 'offer_id', 'brand_id'); // But don't have brand_id column insted I have brand column that contains brand names
}
```

Also, I have tried

```
public function offers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Offer::class, 'offer_brands', 'offer_id', 'brand'); // But Eloquent compare this column with id column of brands table.
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Just in case if someone still looking for an answer .. here's how you can solve this issue.

For example I have roles for users. and the pivot table (`team_users`) has the `user_id`. But instead of containing the `role_id` it contains `role` column which basically is the `slug` of the role in `roles` table.

I can specify the relation exactly like this:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'team_users', 'user_id', 'role', 'id', 'slug');
}
```

Basically `App\Role` is the relation model.

`team_users` is the pivot table name.

`user_id` is the foreign pivot key (So in `team_users` there will be a column called `user_id`)

`role` is the related pivot key (So in `team_users` there will be a column called `role`)

`id` is the parent key (So in `App\User` Laravel will look for the row whose `id` column value equals the foreign pivot key `user_id` in the pivot table).

`slug` is the related key (So in `App\Role` Laravel will look for the row whose `slug` column value equals `role` column in the pivot table)

Comment: If I could click 10 times, I would. Life saver for me. Thanks.

Comment: you deserve a hug !

Comment: good answer saving time

Answer (score 2):

The correct definition:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Offer::class, 'offer_brands', 'brand', 'offer_id');
```

But it's a good idea to use naming conventions. You could name the table `brand_offer` and foreign keys as `offer_id` and `brand_id`. In this case, the relationship would look like this:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Offer::class);
```

Learn more about [Laravel naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions) in my best practices repo.

Comment: It's not an answer to my question. Let me know if I was successful in explaining my problem in the question.

Comment: @AmarjitSingh you have wrong relationship definition. And you can't have FK in other model's table because that's not how many-to-many relationship works. Have you tried to just copy and paste it before downvoting?

Comment: Yes, I did and I got an error unknown column offers.brand and brands.offer_id

Comment: @AmarjitSingh you couldn't possibly get this error with this code.